# In C, how would one take a value from a user defined function, and then print it back out in another user defined function?

Tags: c, function, user-defined-functions, defined

I'm so new to programming. My question relates to an assignment in which I have to create a function that calculates the average of three integers.

That part is pretty straight forward for me, but I also have to create another function that prints out that average, saying something like "The average is %d", whatever. I just have no idea how to get the average from the first function into the second one.

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: The average of a set of numbers is the sum of those items divided by the number of items in the set. Since you have a set of a fixed size, it is `(a + b + c) / 3`.

Answer (score 2):

Hi the first function can return the average using the return type for example `double average(int a1,int a2,int a3) { return (a1+a2+a3)/3.0; }`, in your second function you can :
1. call the average function and store or print the returned value;
2. passing the average value as a function parameter.
3. use the average value as global variable (in this case the average function will not return value)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're referring to "returning" data from a function.

Here's an example:

```
      int addNumbers(int first, int second){
           int third;
           third = first + second;
           return third;
          }
```

This would allow you to call addNumbers(4, 8), and have it give back 12.

```
      printf("The product of 4 and 8 is %d", addNumbers(4,8));
```

I believe this is what  you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
float calculateAverage(int a,int b, int c);
void showAverage(float avg);

int main()
{
     int a,b,c;
     float avg;
     printf("\nEnter value for A: ");
     scanf( "%i", &a);
     printf("\nEnter value for B: ");
     scanf( "%i", &b);
     printf("\nEnter value for C: ");
     scanf( "%i", &c);     
     // calculate the average
     avg = calculateAverage(a,b,c);
     showAverage(avg);
}

float calculateAverage(int a,int b, int c) {
   return (a+b+c)/3.0;
}
void showAverage(float avg)
{
     printf("\nThe average is %f", avg); // &avg is the address we just print we use the value and not the address so don't use &avg but avg
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this...  It's been a LONG time since I used C, but this may get you started...

```
int main()
{
     int a,b,c;
     printf("\nEnter value for A: ");
     scanf( "%i", &a);
     printf("\nEnter value for B: ");
     scanf( "%i", &b);
     printf("\nEnter value for C: ");
     scanf( "%i", &c);     

     // now send those to your function to calculate the average and print the result
     showAverage(a,b,c);
}

function showAverage(int a, int b, int c)
{
     float avg = (a+b+c) / 3;
     printf("\nThe average is %f", &avg);
}
```

Comment: 'void showAverage(int a, int b, int c)' and float avg = (a+b+c) / 3.0;

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I think this is a good way of doing it and I may have to submit it like this but in my assignment, I need a separate function that calculates the average after reading in the values, and then another function specifically for displaying the average. I realise that it's sort of illogical but that's he assignment i've been given. Thanks

Comment: And a cast to skip warnings `(float)(a+b+c) / 3;`